# htaccess block users but not bots

Tags: .htaccess

I have a Wordpress installation in a subfolder and it is used as an API for a SPA. I would like to block users from seeing the wordpress pages, but allow bots to crawl them (angularjs app using `_escaped_fragment_` to serve static content). If it is a user that hits /wordpress/ then redirect to the root

What would the htaccess rules be for this?
Something like this (doesn't work):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/wordpress[/]$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !=(googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm mostly just curious; why would you want to allow bots but not users? That seems backwards. You'll end up confusing people who arrive at your site from search results.

Comment: With an Ajax application you need to serve static html content to a bot for SEO purposes. So users see the Ajax app, bits see static html.